# Deploying MDG Technology with Add-in

Tags: xml, visual-studio, dll, wix, enterprise-architect

I created my own toolbox using Enterprise Architect MDG technology. Also, I create an Addin using Microsoft Visual Studio in C# to add some functionalities of that toolbox.  I would like to generate an installation package of all my works. I use SharpDevelop for that issue and I created a setup file of my Addin.

I have no idea how can I generate .dll files of my toolbox files (XML, and mts) using Microsoft visual studio to can be used by SharpDevelop to create my installation package.

Actually, I saw something like that before but the designer did not give me details  how I can make something similar to that.

Comment: you dont need sharpdevelop to make an installation package if you're using visual Studio, in both cases, you need to use Wix

Comment: Yes, you are right I already use Wix. However, the main issue how can I generate dll files of xml files using Microsoft visual studio.

Comment: Currently looking into it, what I can tell you is you don't need to make a dll for a MDG technology, you can just export the mts and xml

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I like to make integrate my Addin with my MDG technology into one installation package.

Comment: you can deploy a xml file and a dll file at the same time in an installation package, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to generate a dll for your technology, just tell your packager to deploy the .xml file to a folder.

This is done the same way your dll is deployed, minus the generating the dll part.
[Here's a simple guide](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file.html)

---

If you want to deploy the technology to the user's environment:

Deploy your .xml to the `%APPDATA%\Sparx Systems\EA\MDGTechnologies` folder ([source](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/modeling_tools/importmdgtechnologies.html))

---

If you want to import the technology to the model:

Deploy your technology file (xml) to a temporary folder, then load it into your add-in.
Use `EA_OnInitializeTechnologies` Broadcast event to load your technology into the model

I should probably add that you should add a check for the MDG and its version before deploying it, since you don't want the technology to be loaded into the model every time a user opens the model.

References [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/modeling_tools/deploying_mdg_technologies.html) and [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/ea_oninitialize_technologies.html)

---

Difference between deploying to the model and the user environment:

In the user environment, the technology will be available to the user for all models, unless disabled in specific models.

While if deployed to the model, all users will have access to the technology in that model. Even those that do not have the add-in installed.

Comment: I think that what I looking for, you guide is very useful for mine. I will follow all these points and give you the feedback soon.